# Custom Jekyll post types to a subdomain

Tags: jekyll

Without messing about with .htaccess or another Jekyll install, how would one go about having a page or custom post type  route to a subdomain? For example, `_portfolio` would go to `http://portfolio.lendmaico.com/` rather than `http://lendamico.com/portfolio`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would be handled at the DNS and web server level.

1. Update your DNS to make sure that `http://portfolio.lendmaico.com/` resolves to your server (it may already depending on how it's setup).
2. In your web server config, point incoming traffic for 'portfolio.lendmaico.com' to the physical directory path. That is, if your server config is setup to point the main `lendamico.com` domain to `.../some/path/lendamico.com`, you would add a config to point `portfolio.lendmaico.com` to `.../some/path/lendamico.com/portfolio`.

Note that unless you specifically add an htaccess type rule to prevent `http://lendamico.com/portfolio` from showing, you would see the same thing there as `http://portfolio.lendmaico.com/`.

Comment: Yes, that would certainly work. I was imagining something that happened as Jekyll built the site, to know how to construct permalinks and such.